# Как записать в sqlite время?

Tags: python, sqlite

Есть игра, реализованная в виде Telegram бота с БД на sqlite3.
В игре добавлена кнопка "Бонус", которая по задумке должна выдавать рандомное количество игровой валюты раз в 5 минут, к примеру.

Реализация примерно такая:

```
from time import time
from datetime import datetime as dt


# время ожидания в секундах
wait = 300
# храним время получения бонуса, 0 - не получал еще
t = 0
while True:
    if (message.text == 'Получить бонус'):
        timeleft = time()-t
        if t == 0 or (timeleft == waits):
            t = time()
        else:
            print(f'Подождите еще {round((waits-timeleft)/60)} минут')
```

Но вот вопрос: каким образом можно записывать в базу данных sqlite время получения бонуса, чтобы можно было в дальнейшем выдачу бонуса осуществлять отталкиваясь от времени последнего получения бонуса. К примеру, выдавать бонус через 10 часов после последнего получения (время последнего получения бонуса + 10 часов).

Comment: Можна записать в переменную время начала отсчета

Comment: У меня есть код могу скинуть пиши в ЛС @qsobolev

Answer (score 3):

Вы наверняка храните в базе данных профиль пользователя.

Добавьте в профиль ещё одно поле, например `last_bonus_dt`.

При запросе бонуса делайте проверку.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

...
def your_message_handler(message):
    if datetime.now() - last_bonus_dt > timedelta(seconds=300):
        # выдать бонус, записать новое значение `last_bonus_dt`
    else:
        # приходите через N минут
```

Хранить `datetime` в `sqlite` можно в формате ISO

```py
# для сохранения в текстовый формат
string = datetime.isoformat(dt)

# для получения datetime из строки
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(string)
```

Comment: так весь вопрос  в том, как в это поле поместить дату и время получения бонуса. Ведь sqlite не поддерживает запись в виде HH:MM:SS

Comment: добавил информацию в ответ

Comment: @JorjCornev Т.к. HH:MM:SS - строка, то как раз поддерживает.